# UIButton behavior changes if collectionView moveItemAt is overridden

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionview

I have a collection view controller. One of collection view's cells contains a button with Touch Down and Touch Up Inside.

Strictly speaking, the button is in the view of view controller which is a subview of the collection view cell.

When the button is pressed the Touch Down is fired and when the button is released the Touch Up Inside is fired. Until the button is not released the button is grayed and the  Touch Up Inside is not fired.

This is exactly the behaviour I need.

Now, I have implemented these two methods to support reordering collection view's cells:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
```

If the second method is implemented (both if canMoveItemAt returns true or false), the button behavior changes:

- as soon as the button is pressed, fires the Touch Down event and immediately after that, it also fires the Touch Up Inside event.
- - the button is grayed when pressed and immediately gets back to its normal state like it has been released
  - when the button is released, nothing happens

My suspect is that events propagate from button to the collection view controller, but I have no idea how to prevent it.

Can anyone help me?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

You are right, but if you stop it, you stop reordering as well. Basically you need to choose what do you need: button to be pressed or cell to be dragged. Perhaps you can achive expected behaviour utilising  Collection cell capabilities, instead of button. You can easily change button states, if you need button to represent that cell is being dragged.